# How to know which C# compiler provided by Mono project in my Linux YOCTO SDK toolchain and how to call it?

Tags: c#, sdk, mono, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using **Yocto project** to build Linux kernel image.

In order to run **C# .NET core applications**, I added **Mono** into my Linux image :

- Clone `meta-mono` layer
- Add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mono"` / `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "mono-dev"` in **local.conf** file
- Add the `meta-mono` layer in **bblayers.conf** file
- Bitbake the image : `bitbake core-image-minimal`

Mono packages are provided my SDK toolchain now :

- cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0
- mono-dbg cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0
- mono-dev cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0
- mono-gac cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0
- mono-libs cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0
- mono-libs-4.5 cortexa5hf-neon 5.12.0.226-r0

After that, I source the envirnoment script :

```
source /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/environment-setup-cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

The script is used to call the compilers of my SDK toolchain and for C/C++ compilers I can use `echo ${CC}` or `echo ${CXX}` in order to know the compilers informations.

Now, I want to know which **C#** cross compiler is provided by mono ? How to call it in order to build my C# code ? I must source the script for it ? Is there some commands like `echo ${CC}` or `echo ${CXX}` for C# compiler informations ?

Thanks!

Comment: "In order to run C# .NET core applications, I added Mono into my Linux image" is completely wrong. .NET Core applications can be published as self-contained so no other dependencies are needed, or framework dependent so you just need .NET Core runtime, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ Mono is never needed.

Comment: @LexLi sorry but what do you mean by `published as self-contained` ?

Comment: @LexLi you mean that I just have to only install .NET core on my local host machine and compile the C# code to have an executable for ARM platform. Than I can run that ARM executable on my embedded board without installing .NET core or mono on that ARM board ?

Comment: Get some hints from posts like https://taras.codes/blog/hosting-an-asp-net-core-application-on-raspberry-pi-3/